# ¿Cómo hacer un onclick de un elemento append? JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me explico. quiero crear varios elemento

```
$("#restriction").click(function(){
      efect = false; //No tiene nada que ver
      redraw(); //Tampoco tiene algo que ver
      v = $('#inputRess').val();
      if (v <= 1) {
        $("#Nanswer").html("<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show' role='alert'><strong>¡Ups!&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>Al menos dos restricciónes.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close' onclick='inputRess.disabled=false;'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>");
      }else{
        $(".boxAcount").hide();
        //NgenerarM();
        mat = "";
        for(var k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
            mat += "<label class='obj"+k+"' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' tooltip-title='Introduzca el objeto/utilidad N°"+(k+1)+".'>";
            mat += "<div class='input-group input-group-sm'>";
            mat += "<div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text' id='basic-addon1'>Objeto "+(k+1)+"</span></div>";
            mat += "<input type='text' class='form-control' id='ob"+k+"'>";
            mat += "</div></label>";
        }
        mat += "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block' id='afterObj'>Block level button</button>";
        $("#Nmatriz").append(mat); //Acá creo todos los elementos
      }
});
$("#afterObj").click(function(){ //Acá quiero usar el button creado en el último mat llamado afterObj
    $("#Nmatriz").append('hola');
});
```

Pero a la vez quiero usarlos. No sé si se puede, pero al intentarlo el boton ni siquiera envía a consola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que no enlazas el evento click con los nuevos elementos, es decir creas elementos y creastes el evento click pero nunca lo enlazas es decir cada uno anda por su lado; hice un ejemplo resumido de lo que tu estas haciendo y el otro como deberias de hacerlo:

**Como tu lo tienes:**

```js
$("#agregar").click(function(){
  
  let htmlE = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block' id='afterObj'>Block level button</button>";
   
  $("#nuevos-elementos").append(htmlE);
   
});

$("#afterObj").click(function(){ 
  alert("Si, me distes click!!!")
});
```

```css
#nuevos-elementos{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="agregar">Agregar nuevo elementos</button>

<div id="nuevos-elementos"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Como veras es un ejemplo similar al tuyo donde vas creando nuevos elementos y creas el evento click pero nunca se entienden, ahora te colocare como debe de ser:

```js
$("#agregar").click(function(){
  
  let htmlE = "<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-block afterObj'>Block level button</button>";
   
  $("#nuevos-elementos").append(htmlE);
  $(".afterObj:last").on("click",function(){
    alert("Si, me distes click!!!, soy el botón "+($(this).index()+1)+" creado")
  });
   
});
```

```css
#nuevos-elementos{
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button id="agregar">Agregar nuevo elementos</button>

<div id="nuevos-elementos"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Aquí movi el evento click inmediatamente luego del `append()` ya que estoy creando el elemento e inmdiatamente le asigno el evento click, tambien le hice referencia a dicho objeto por la clase y no por un id porque si lo haces solo por el id solo te hara el vento click el primero y los demas no. En resumen el problema era el momento en el cual debes asignar el evento. Espero que sea lo que andas buscando.

Comment: Hola @DavidLeonardoMolinaRuizDav he observado algunas de sus respuesta la mayor parte sobre `jQuery` o `javascript` puedes echarme una mano con esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203464/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-datos-y-filtros-de-paginaci%C3%B3n-avanzada-con-ajax) por favor, estoy tratando de crear una paginación con `ajax` hasta el momento he logrado traer los datos pero no se como generar los botones de la paginación y con enviar información al `ajax` y que este me la muestre por ejemplo en el filtro de mostrar más filas de resultados, puedes ayudarme :)

Comment: Claro mi info esta en mi perfil mañana comunicate conmigo ya voy de salida, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendí mi error

Answer (score 3):

Los elementos que se vayan agregando después de la carga inicial del DOM no son reconocidos pero si son existentes, por lo cual debes usar `delegate` para asignar los eventos a hijos dada una selección particular y no un elemento especifico.
Para usar `delegate` debes seleccionar un contenedor padre y asignar la acción en los hijos.

Ejemplo:

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "p", "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Otro ejemplo:

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "p", "click", function() {
  $( this ).after( "<p>Another paragraph!</p>" ); 
});
```

También puedes delegar un evento en el evento de la siguiente manera:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```