# codigo ajax con php para form

Tags: php, ajax

he estado batallando para realizar ciertas cosas en una pagina que he creado, el rollo va que cuando escribo en un formulario me gustaria que no me lanze a el archivo php que me inserta en la DB entonces he leido mucho sobre ajax me gustaria saber como hacer para que al insertar en el formulario no me lleve a ese doc php pero si me inserte en mi DB y a su vez me refresque la pagina.

espero me puedan ayudar dando un ejemplo claro, soy nuevo en php y aun mas en ajax desconozco completamente sobre esto.

Comment: Te copio este resumen que redacté en otra respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203464/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-datos-y-filtros-de-paginaci%c3%b3n-avanzada-con-ajax/203496#203496

Comment: no encuentro un ejemplo que me ayude :(