# ¿Cómo mostrar datos en paginación usando Ajax, JSON, PHP y MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, mysqli

Esta es mi estructura `HTML`, un diseño simple:

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
}
.justify-between {
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.table-header {
    padding: 2em;
}
.search-bar {
    position: relative;
    width: 34%;
}
input.go-seeker {
    border-radius: 1em;
    right: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1.2em;
    height: 2.4em;
    border: 1px solid #363535;
    background-color: #333;
    outline: none;
    color: #999898;
}
input.go-seeker:focus {
    width: 70%;
    right: 0em;
}
button.btn-search {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 2em;
    right: 2px;
    top: 0.3em;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 2em;
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    outline: none;
}
button.btn-search:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    top: 4px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-image: url(../img/website/svg/search.svg);
}
.table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.bootgrid-table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: left;
}
.table td {
    overflow: hidden;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.table>tbody>tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.table>tbody>tr:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.table > thead > tr > th,
.table > tbody > tr > th,
.table > tfoot > tr > th,
.table > thead > tr > td,
.table > tbody > tr > td,
.table > tfoot > tr > td {
    padding: 8px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*border-top: 1px solid #ddd;*/
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > th,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > th,
.table > caption + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > colgroup + thead > tr:first-child > td,
.table > thead:first-child > tr:first-child > td {
    /*border-top: 0;*/
}
.table > thead > tr > th {
    vertical-align: bottom;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

span#add,
span.view_data,
span.edit_data {
    cursor: pointer;
}

i.icon-delete:hover,
i.icon-add-new:hover,
i.icon-view:hover,
i.icon-edit:hover {
    filter: brightness(40%);
}

.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination>li {
    display: inline;
}
.pagination>li:first-child>a, .pagination>li:first-child>span {
    margin-left: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.pagination>.disabled>a,
.pagination>.disabled>a:focus,
.pagination>.disabled>a:hover,
.pagination>.disabled>span,
.pagination>.disabled>span:focus,
.pagination>.disabled>span:hover {
    color: #777;
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ddd;
}
.pagination>li>a, .pagination>li>span {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #337ab7;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pagination>li>a.active {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
    <div class="bootgrid"> 
        <div class="flex justify-between table-header">
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <div class="actions btn-group">
                    <label>
                        <select id="amount_show" name="amount_show">
                            <option value="10" selected="">10</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="50">50</option>
                            <option value="100">100</option>
                        </select>
                            entries
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <select id="customer" name="customer">
                        <option value="1">Google</option>
                        <option value="2">StackOverflow</option>
                        <option value="3">PayPal</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="datetime" name="">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="search" name="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table id="data-table" class="table bootgrid-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>ID Customer</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Rol</th>
                    <th>Register Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody-insert"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Los datos se imprimen correctamente en PHP, el problema viene del código `ajax` que no me muestra los resultados en la paginación:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id_user,
                                id_customer,
                                name,
                                email,
                                rol,
                                register_date
                            FROM users
                            ORDER BY id_user DESC");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id_user, $id_customer, $name, $email, $rol, $register_date);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $data['users'][] = [
        'id_user' => $id_user,
        'id_customer' => $id_customer,
        'email' => $email,
        'rol' => $rol,
        'register_date' => $register_date
    ];
}
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode($data);
```

La realización de un `console.log (data);` me muestra que los datos también se están llamando o recibiendo correctamente, pero no muestra esos resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: "json",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        tableRows = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tableRows += `
                <tr>
                    <td>${data[i].id_user}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].id_customer}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].email}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].rol}</td>
                    <td>${data[i].register_date}</td>
                    <td>Edit<td>
                </tr>`;
        }
        $("#tbody-insert").html(tableRows);
    })
});
```

Mi idea es crear una paginación con varios filtros; por cantidad de resultados, por fecha, por filtro de cliente, por filtro de rol y, un motor de búsqueda.

Estoy migrando a `JSON` ya que supieron mencionarme que *desde PHP solo envíe datos en formato `JSON`, que me ayudará a reducir significativamente el contenido de cada petición y, por consiguiente, el tiempo de respuesta`

Basado a la siguiente pregunta:

- [¿Cómo mostrar datos y filtros de paginación avanzada con ajax?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203464/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-datos-y-filtros-de-paginaci%c3%b3n-avanzada-con-ajax)

Comment: No veo que estes paginando ni en JS, ni en PHP, por lo que diría que no hay error porque directamente no lo estas haciendo. ¿Queres saber como se podría paginar? Si la idea es _"reducir significativamente el contenido"_ te diría que tenes que paginar en `PHP`

Comment: @Marcos En realidad si, saber cómo hacerlo pero en Ajax ya tenía un ejemplo funcionando pero recomendaron mostrar datos en `json` y no en `html` entiendo que falta código en php para realizarlo pero como ya no es en `html` ya no podría generarlo con `PHP` sino solo datos en `json` si tenía este código: https://jsfiddle.net/ycma3j0k/ estaba reducido completamente se podría decir porque estaba todo separado, es decir el archivo php que generaba los datos de la paginacion y, en el Ajax / jQuery solo eran pocas líneas de código y, funcionaba perfectamente, ahora lo estoy intentando en `json`

Comment: @Marcos pero sin éxito, no tengo mucho conocimiento en jQuery/Javascript pero lo intento tomando ejemplos que tengo o que encuentro.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando como punto de partida el código de [tu comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/446890/error-al-mostrar-datos-en-paginaci%c3%b3n-usando-ajax-php-y-mysql?noredirect=1#comment796587_446890) (*el cual si tiene paginación*) las modificaciones que podrías realizar son:

- La generación del HTML de páginas la realizamos con Javascript.
  Para poder hacer esto necesitamos enviar dentro del JSON de respuesta **la página actual** (ej: `current_page`), el **total de registros** (ej: `total_records`) y el **la cantidad de registros por página** (ej: `records_by_page`).
- Para obtener el total de registros usamos la función [`COUNT(*)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) de MySQL, que es mucho mas eficiente que devolver todos los registros para saber cuantos son.

#### Ejemplo:

**PHP**

```
<?php

// Controlamos los datos recibidos para paginar
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
if ($page < 1) $page = 1;
$records_by_page = isset($_GET['amount_show']) ? (int) $_GET['amount_show'] : 10;
if ($records_by_page < 10) $records_by_page = 10;

$limit_from = ($page - 1) * $records_by_page;

// Inicializamos el arreglo de respuesta.
$response = [
    'records' => [],
    'current_page' => $page,
    'records_by_page' => $records_by_page,
    'total_records' => 0,
];

// Obtenemos el total de registros
$info = $con->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM users")->fetch_assoc();
$response['total_records'] = $info['total'];

// Obtenemos los registros para la "pagina actual"
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT 
        id_user,
        id_customer,
        name,
        email,
        rol,
        register_date
    FROM users
    ORDER BY id_user DESC
    LIMIT $limit_from, $records_by_page");

$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while($user = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $response['records'][] = $user;
}

// Imprimimos la respuesta
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bootgrid"> 
    <div class="flex justify-between table-header">
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="actions btn-group">
                <label>
                    <select id="amount_show" name="amount_show">
                        <option value="10" selected="">10</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="50">50</option>
                        <option value="100">100</option>
                    </select>
                        entries
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="customer" name="customer">
                    <option value="1">Google</option>
                    <option value="2">StackOverflow</option>
                    <option value="3">PayPal</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="datetime" name="">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="search" name="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table id="data-table" class="table bootgrid-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ID Customer</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Rol</th>
                <th>Register Date</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody-insert"></tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="7" id="tfoot-paging"></td>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```js
    $(function() {
      // Click en el paginado
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination li a', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        ajaxLoad($(this).data('page'));
      });

      // Cambio de valor
      $('#amount_show').change(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        ajaxLoad(1); // ACA volvemos a la pagina 1 porque la config cambió
      });

      ajaxLoad(1);

      // Función que busca los registros
      function ajaxLoad(page) {

        let endpoint = "ajax.php";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: endpoint,
            data: {
              page: page,
              amount_show: $('#amount_show').val(),
              // ACA agregar los demas filtros aplicados, ej:
              customer: $('#customer').val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
          })
          .done(function(data) {
            // Recorremos el arreglo de datos y creamos las filas
            let rows = '',
              users = data.records;
            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
              rows += `
                    <tr>
                        <td>${users[i].id_user}</td>
                        <td>${users[i].id_customer}</td>
                        <td>${users[i].name}</td>
                        <td>${users[i].email}</td>
                        <td>${users[i].rol}</td>
                        <td>${users[i].register_date}</td>
                        <td>Edit<td>
                    </tr>`;
            }
            $("#tbody-insert").html(rows);

            // Creamos el paginado
            $("#tfoot-paging").html(createPaging({
              url: endpoint,
              current_page: data.current_page,
              total_records: data.total_records,
              records_by_page: data.records_by_page
            }));
          });
      }

      // Funcion para crear el paginado según la configruación recibida
      function createPaging(data) {
        let html = '<div class="pagination"><ul class="pagination">',
          total_pages = Math.ceil(data.total_records / data.records_by_page);

        if (data.current_page > 1) {
          html += `<li><a data-page="1"><i class="icon-angle-double-arrow"></i></a></li>
                <li><a data-page="${data.current_page - 1}"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a></li>`;
        }

        for (let i = 1; i <= total_pages; i++) {
          if (data.current_page == i) {
            html += `<li><a class="page-link active">${i}</a></li>`;
          } else {
            html += `<li><a class="page-link" data-page="${i}">${i}</a></li>`;
          }
        }

        if (data.current_page < total_pages) {
          html += `<li><a class="page-link" data-page="${data.current_page + 1}"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="page-link" data-page="${total_pages}"><i class="icon-angle-double-right"></i></a></li>`;
        }

        html += '</ul></div>';
        return html;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Hola @Marcos adapte el código PHP sin `get_result()` ni el uso de ``fetch_assoc()` quedando de la siguiente manera https://ideone.com/NToECy me imprime el mismo resultado y, me muestra los datos. El problema es que no esta creando los botones de la paginación, en ambos formatos de PHP no los muestras, amigo puedes agregarle el filtro de fecha y, un buscador, puedes explicarme un poquito más para yo poder añadir más filtros sin problemas como el filtro de cliente, filtro del rol de usuario etc.

Comment: Mi +1. Revisando el código para entender su funcionamiento, vi que le falta un ` en esta línea al final y le sobra un ": ```html += `<li><a class="page-link" data-page="${i}">${i}</a></li>";```, quizás si lo pones así ```html += `<li><a class="page-link" data-page="${i}">${i}</a></li>`;``` añadiendo al final el `, te soluciona el problema que comentas @J.Mick

Comment: @DBE, gracias por tu comentario

Comment: @J.Mick, agregue un par de correciones mas, avisame cualquier cosa. Respecto a los filtros, eso ya escapa al scope de tu pregunta. ¿Nunca has aplicado filtros (_condiciones_) a una consulta SQL?

Comment: Hola @DBE Si corregí amigo, fui estudiando el código línea por línea :) voy a revisar la actualización.

Comment: @Marcos Si amigo, todo al respecto a PHP sin problemas, he actualizado su código sin uso de `get_result()` en ello cero inconvenientes, mi mayor problema es `javascript` :/ el cual no tengo conocimientos algunas penas lo entiendo.

Comment: @J.Mick, ¿tuviste algún problema después de la actualización de mi respuestas? Respecto a agregar filtros, si te fijas en mi `Javascript` puse en ejemplo de como enviar `customer` (_solo faltaría usar su valor en `PHP` para filtrar_)