# Sumar días a un día obtenido a traves de un $_GET

Tags: php, html, variables, post, get

Estoy intentando hacer una especie de paginación de días, donde solo se puede aumentar el día infinitamente, obtengo el día a través de una variable `$_GET`:

```
$diaHoy = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("-5 hours"));
if (!isset($_GET['d'])) {
    $_SESSION['dia'] = $diaHoy;
    $dia = $diaHoy;
} else {
    $_SESSION['dia'] = $_GET['d'];
    $dia = $_GET['d'];
}
$diaSiguiente = date("d/m/Y", strtotime(strtotime(".$dia.") . "+ 1 days"));
echo "El Dia Actual es: $dia<br>";
echo "El Dia Siguiente es: $diaSiguiente<br>";

echo '<a href="agenda.php?d=' . $diaSiguiente . '">Siguiente</a>';
```

La primera vez, la variable `$diaSiguiente` si muestra el día siguiente, sin embargo, cuando ya estoy en la página del día siguiente, el día siguiente me lo sigue marcando como ese mismo día.

¿Qué está mal en mi código, cómo podría hacer para que la variable `$diaSiguiente` siempre sea, en efecto, el día siguiente?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo mostrar datos y filtros de paginación avanzada con ajax?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203464/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-datos-y-filtros-de-paginaci%c3%b3n-avanzada-con-ajax)

Comment: Hola, parece que no usas bien las fechas, date() se usa para dar formato a una fecha, pero no para obtener la fecha. Mejor usa el objeto DateTime y DateInterval para sumar el día. El plantemiento general es bueno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que la fecha con "/" el strtotime procesa con formato americano ("m/d/y"), lo que puedes hacer es sustituir las "/" por "-" para que la fecha la interprete con formato europeo ("d-m-y") y devuelva el tiempo adecuado

En este enlace puedes encontrar la observación https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#100144

Tu instrucción quedaría:

```
$diaSiguiente = date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$dia) . "+ 1 days"));
```

y tu código resultante:

```
$diaHoy = date("d/m/Y", strtotime("-5 hours"));

if (!isset($_GET['d'])) {
    $_SESSION['dia'] = $diaHoy;
    $dia = $diaHoy;
} else {
    $_SESSION['dia'] = $_GET['d'];
    $dia = $_GET['d'];
}

$diaSiguiente = date("d/m/Y", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',$dia) . "+ 1 days"));
echo "El Dia Actual es: $dia<br>";
echo "El Dia Siguiente es: $diaSiguiente<br>";

echo '<a href="agenda.php?d=' . $diaSiguiente . '">Siguiente</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes realizar esto

$diaSiguiente = $dia + date("d",strtotime("+1 day"));

var_dump($diaSiguiente);

En todo caso para que no se pierda, lo pones en variable de session.

Answer (score 0):

Usando objetos fecha

```
$diaHoy = date_create('now', new DateTimeZone('-0500'));
if (!isset($_GET['d'])) {
    $_SESSION['dia'] = $diaHoy->format('d-m-Y');
    $dia = $diaHoy->format('d-m-Y');
} else {
    $_SESSION['dia'] = $_GET['d'];
    $dia = $_GET['d'];
    $diaHoy = date_create($dia);
}
$diaSiguiente = $diaHoy->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
echo "El Dia Actual es: $dia<br>";
echo "El Dia Siguiente es:".$diaSiguiente->format('d-m-Y')."<br>";
echo '<a href="agenda.php?d='.$diaSiguiente->format('d-m-Y').'">Siguiente</a>';
```

Me gusta usar objetos, el código suele quedar más claro. Si te animas verás que son muy cómodos de usar.