# como mostrar por defecto registro de 6 meses de antiguedad en php ajax

Tags: php, sql, ajax

buenas tardes tengo ya listo una busqueda por rango de fecha el prolema ahora es que si no coloco fechas y le doy a filtrar necesito que me traiga los ultimos 6 meses de registro... eso se hace en js o a nivel de query ?

```
      var fecha_1 = String($('#fecha_inicio').val().replace(/-/g,"")); //aqui estamos reemplazando los guiones (-) q trae la separacion de fecha por espacios en blanco o vacios
      var fecha_2 = String($('#fecha_fin').val().replace(/-/g,"")) //aqui estamos reemplazando los guiones (-) q trae la separacion de fecha por espacios en blanco o vacios
      
      fecha_1_ = unix_date_ccr_pcr(parseInt(new Date($('#fecha_inicio').val()).getTime()+14400000))
      fecha_2_ = unix_date_ccr_pcr(parseInt(new Date($('#fecha_fin').val()).getTime()+82800000))
      var fecha_limite = adaptar_fecha((new Date()).getTime()+86400000)

      var rango = fecha_2-fecha_1

    if ((fecha_1 == ""))
    {
        des_reportes_error('LA FECHA DE INICIO SE ENCUENTRA VACIA')
        return false;
    }
    if  ((fecha_2 == "")) 
    {
        des_reportes_error('LA FECHA DE FIN SE ENCUENTRA VACIA ')
        return false;
    }


$.ajax({
        url:"Solicitudes_Ctr/_filtrado",
        type:"post",
        datatype: "json",
        data:{'fecha_1':fecha_1_, 'fecha_2':fecha_2_},
        error: function(jqXHR){
            var error = error_ajax(jqXHR);
        }


 $query = $db_profile->query( "SELECT region,tck,id_solicitud,fecha_corta,tipo_solicitud,    clasificado,responsable,tarea,cantidad , ciudad,    codigo,descripcion,proveedor,   FROM solicitudes  WHERETO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(fecha_corta, 'DD/MM/YY'), 'YYYYMMDD'))   BETWEEN $fecha1 AND $fecha2 " );
```

Comment: Yo diría que lo debes hacer con **PHP**, por ejemplo, en *Solicitudes_Ctr/_filtrado* allí puedes hacer una valoración si los filtros están vacíos, si este es el caso obtienes la *query* con los datos por defecto (últimos 6 meses), y en caso de que si existen los filtros pues ya creas la *query* con dichos parámetros filtrando los datos. Para que te pueden ayudar mejor, sería bueno que añades **Solicitudes_Ctr/_filtrado.php** a tu pregunta.

Comment: Desde que muestras el formulario asigna las fechas por defecto, así siempre tendrás el filtro activo y el usuario sabrá lo que va a ver.

Comment: Te dejo varios respuesta del **SOes** muy buenas, como puedes filtrar datos: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203464/c%c3%b3mo-mostrar-datos-y-filtros-de-paginaci%c3%b3n-avanzada-con-ajax